# Meteor: publish intersection of find

Tags: meteor, publish, intersection

I have a collection as below:

```js
Schema.Place = new SimpleSchema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function(){ return 'Point'; }
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        decimal:true,
    },
});

Schema.Direction = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
    },
    from: {
        type: Schema.Place,
    },
    to: {
        type: Schema.Place,
    }
});
```

I then want to query the same directions according to the *from* and *to* points. The first problem is that I can't query two geo index in the very same query so I do as follow:

```js
Meteor.publish('Directions', function(direction){
    var ids = Ride.find({
        active: true,
        from: {
            $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: direction.from.coordinates,
                },
                $maxDistance: 5000,
            }
        }
    }).map(function(item){return item._id});

    return Ride.find({
        _id: {$in: ids},
        to :{
            $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: direction.to.coordinates,
                },
                $maxDistance: 5000,
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is that publish loses its reactivity due to the double query filtering...

I have some ideas how to do the job but it seems pretty weird to me there is no better way to do so:

- Publish the first query and do the filtering on client (but not sure
  $near is supported client side though)
- Use observeChanges in the publish function
- Use a meteor method in publish function (I've seen it in an old discussion but not sure whether it is possible or relevant to my problem).

Comment: you can use `publish composite` package for reactive join `https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite`

Comment: I already use it but it is meant for parent/child relation, isn't it? How can I use it for the very same collection?

Comment: yes it's meant for parent/children relation. but you can query the same collection in the children.